# Should I install 32-bit database or 64-bit database?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-server-2008, postgresql, 32bit-64bit

*(I've read a lot about 64-bit versus 32-bit OS/Apps, but this question is specifically in regards to databases.)*

I'm trying to understand the pros and cons of 32-bit versus 64-bit databases, and namely, under what conditions that it starts to make sense to use 64-bit installations.

The database systems that I am interested in are: SQL Server 2008, MySQL, and PostgreSQL 9.0.

I have read that pre-9.0 versions of PostgreSQL only comes in 32-bit for Windows, and this [article about running 32-bit PostgreSQL on 64-bit Windows](http://blog.hagander.net/archives/73-PostgreSQL-vs-64-bit-windows.html) clears up some of my confusion, but I'm looking for more info.

When would I benefit from using 64-bit databases (i.e. database size/disk space, available system memory, types of data sernarios that are known to benefit from it, which database engine being used, etc.)?

Comment: You could probably get some good answers to this on serverfault.com

Comment: What kind of a database are you looking to run? Is reaching Gigabyte limits an issue at all?

Comment: @Pekka: I am not in danger of hitting disk space limits at all.

Comment: @BenV: is there a way to move this question to serverfault?

Comment: Closed and moved here: http://serverfault.com/questions/160082/should-i-install-32-bit-database-or-64-bit-database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a 64-bit capable OS and processor, the most important advantage of 64-bits is the ability to use more than 4GB of memory.

Comment: Well, I obviously have more than 4 GB, but I'm not yet sure if I'm efficiently using all that memory right now.